# List changed files of a Pull Request using powershell or git

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

I require to list the list of files modified in particular pull request in Azure DevOps Server 2019 git repo.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there's no direct Rest-Api to do that. You can first use [Get Pull Request Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20commits/get%20pull%20request%20commits?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get commits for one specific PR, and then use [Get changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20changes?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) in a loop to get the files changed in one PR.

The `path` element in changes indicates the changed file. But for now no Azure Devops Rest-api can directly list all the changed files' names.

**In addition:** You may consider using `git command` instead of `Rest-api` to do that job. Similar issues see [How can I see all modified files from a Git Pull Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139485/how-can-i-see-all-modified-files-from-a-git-pull-request) and [List all files changed in a pull request in Git/GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071579/list-all-files-changed-in-a-pull-request-in-git-github). Hope it helps :)