# Get changed files list for one Pull Request

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I also need to require to list the list of files modified in particular pull request in Azure DevOps services.

I have checked some threads, like [List changed files of a Pull Request using powershell or git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60391816/list-changed-files-of-a-pull-request-using-powershell-or-git), but it not given the solution. Most of the answers are for github, not azure devops.

So, I'm wondering if there is such a direct git command to fetch it, and if not, how can this be achieved using the corresponding Azure Devops REST API script? Please help.

**Background：**

I created a pipeline which is triggered by the PR (Build Validation) on the `SIT` branch:

[image]

The configuration of the pipeline is as follow：

[image]

The `ModifiedFileTest` is the my test branch name, which based on the `SIT` branch:

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LeGEC's answer is correct.

In Azure DevOps Pipeline, you need to set the remote source, then you can run git diff to get the changed files.

Example:

```
git remote add  origin1 RepoURL
git remote update    
git diff  origin1/test  origin1/master
```

Then we can get the changed files.

Answer (score 2):

If you have up to date branches in your local clone, the diff or the "merge request view" for branch `feature` into `main` is:

```
git diff origin/main...origin/feature   # 3 dots, not a typo
```

*note:* the behavior of this syntax is documented in the ["Description" section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203-1) of `git help diff`

It basically shows the diff between `origin/feature` and "the point where it forked off `origin/main`", and all the platforms I know of (github, gitlab, azure devops, bitbucket ...) show this diff in their "Pull Request" view.

---

You can add any other suitable option to `git diff`, like `--name-only` or `--name-status` :

```
# list of files modified in 'feature':
git diff --name-only origin/main...origin/feature

# list+status of files modified in 'feature':
git diff --name-status origin/main...origin/feature
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I got the error message "fatal: ambiguous argument 'branch1...branch2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'"

Comment: That's the error you get when one of the names you used doesn't exist. Double check the names you typed for your branches.